# Meaning of 'i' type in HaXml

Tags: haskell, haxml

At the documentation page of HaXml ([here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HaXml/1.22.5/doc/html/Text-XML-HaXml-Types.html#t%3aDocument)), everywhere used type `i`, for example: `Document i`, `Element i`, `Content i` and so forth. But I can't find what kind of type it is, and where it's being used? Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lower-case letters in a type represent *type variables*.  That is, you can put any type you want in there.  In the case of HaXml it is meant to store some extra information in the `Content` type.  There also is a function `info` that retrieves this extra information (although for some weird reason the parameter is called `t` instead of `i`).

If you look at [Text.XML.HaXml.Parse](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HaXml/1.22.5/doc/html/Text-XML-HaXml-Parse.html) you can see that this extra parameter is used to store the source location (`Posn`) of the parsed document.